# I can't get email or profile scopes for an Azure B2C application, nor can I call the OIDC UserInfo endpoint

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm finding Azure B2C really confusing. Currently I am using oauth2_proxy behind an nginx ingress controller in a test (single node) AKS kubernetes environment. I have made a slight change to oauth2_proxy to redirect upon error to chain Workflows together (like password recovery link etc.) and everything is working so far. I get an authorisation cookie from oath2_proxy and the ingress controller lets me through.

My next step is to work out what the username is, and maybe gather some more informaton. I think I can get some of the information in the id_token, but I am failing to see "email" and "preferred_username". Apparently these are only available if my token has the "email" and "profile" scopes, but I cannot work out how to get those scopes on my B2C App.

Currently I have a test application. In it's API permissions area I have a single "read" permission so that I have a resource to request to get an access_token. I also have "email", "offline_access", "openid", "profile" and "User.Read" permissions from "Microsoft Graph" - all permissions are granted by the admin on the API permissions screen.

The process I have been following up to now for testing is to run a signin workflow, selecting my API in the resources dropdown. I then copy the "Code" into a token request in postman, and then try both the "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" and the "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo" endpoints with both the "id_token" and the "access_token". Both of these respond with "InvalidAuthenticationToken", message "Access token validation failure".

I had since noticed that my resources dropdown still only contains "read" and "openid" access rights, so I have been copying the "run userflow" url and inserting the scopes for "email", "offline_access", "openid" and "profile". I have also ensured that my call to the "token" endpoint contains these scopes. The response from the token endpoint only returns scopes "read offline_access openid", so "profile" and "email" are missing.

I don't know how to configure my app registration in B2C so that the "email" and "profile" scopes become available. Since "openid" appears in the resource drop down, I would expect "email" and "profile to turn up in there, but they don't. My token calls definitely show that the scopes that I need are not returned.

My workflow url looks as follows:

```
https://********.b2clogin.com/********.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_signup_signin&client_id=********&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid%20user.read%20email%20profile%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2F********.onmicrosoft.com%2Ftestapp%2Fread&response_type=code&prompt=login
```

My token call looks as follows (using the code value from the workflow):

```
https://********.b2clogin.com/********/b2c_1_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=********&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&response_mode=query&scope=https://********.onmicrosoft.com/apptest/read openid offline_access email profile&code=******CODE FROM WORKFLOW CALLBACK******
```

Token response is like:

```
{
    "access_token": "******BIG LONG BASE64******",
    "id_token": "******BIG LONG BASE64******",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not_before": 1591607270,
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "expires_on": 1591610870,
    "resource": "********",
    "id_token_expires_in": 3600,
    "profile_info": "******BASE64******",
    "scope": "https://********.onmicrosoft.com/testapp/read offline_access openid",
    "refresh_token": "******BASE64******",
    "refresh_token_expires_in": 1209600
}
```

OIDC endpoint call like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo

HAS HEADERS
Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization: Bearer ********BASE64 from access_token********
```

Any help would be appreciated. i.e. how do I return additional scopes + how do I call the OIDC UserInfo endpoint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with a similar issue a while back, where I wanted my API to use the access token to look up user info. Azure AD does not work in a standards compliant way:

- Calling User Info requires a separate graph token
- You have to use a token exchange request to get the graph token

Here are some resources of mine which I think are related and will hopefully give you enough info to resolve your problem. I think right now you are getting the error from Step 14 of the blog post.

- [Token Exchange + User Info Lookup C# Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts)
- [Blog Post on Azure AD Settings related to Graph / User Info](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/)

Comment: Thanks Gary, I think I'd worked out that I have to log in to Graph before i wrote this message. The problem is that I've been working with a component called oauth2_proxy and I was hoping to implement a profile fetch to fill in required details. Logging in to Graph seems to start an oauth2 grants routine, so I was in the absurd position of having to do a user-facing authentication process so that another user-facing authentication process could load some data. I have since pulled the data from the token. I'll read through your links later.

Comment: Oh - I just remembered that the real problem was that when I tried to access Graph, it wanted to log me in as my Azure login proper (the one that I use for admin), not the one that I'm trying to work with via B2C for my app - Again - I'll try and glean some information from your links.

Comment: Good to hear that you've resolved your problem Mark. In a nutshell I found that using a single 'default' scope in the UI allows you to use a single login redirect. You can then use back end 'on behalf of / token exchange' capabilities to access additional resources and serve them to the UI. I agree with you that it's confusing, lol ...

Comment: @GaryArcher where is the Step 14? I'm having some trouble with OIDC x QlikSense and I think is the same problem.